# How to align alert and button on one row?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
 <div class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="alert alert-danger">alert</div>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </div>
```

I want to put alert and button on one row, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div` is a block level element.

Use `span` instead :

```
 <div class="form-horizontal">
   <span class="alert alert-danger">alert</span>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Only alert's height  is bigger than button's. How to make they same high

Answer (score 0):

```
 .alert
 {
 float:left;
 }

.btn-primary
 {
float:right;
}
```